# Getting EXDATE to work when creating Google recurring event

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I am trying to import a recurring calendar event using a RRULE plus EXDATE to exclude a date.  I thought I had this working a while ago, but it seems to not work any more, at least for this example. The problem is the EXDATE is ignored.  See below for sample json.  I am trying to exclude the first instance, which begins on June 17, 2019.  The date is in Zulu and should match the start date of the event, i.e. 0900 Chicago is 1400 GMT. I have tried including the TZID value of America/Chicago, putting the time in local time (without the Z) and also varying the time up and down by one hour.  Google won't budge, the first date is always included in the series.  What am I doing wrong?

```
{
 "summary": "Test Meeting 01",
 "description": "\n",
 "location": "",
 "iCalUID": "B8537ED49F7A60558625840A00697C87-Lotus_Notes_Generated-1559329993",
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2019-06-17T09:00:00-05:00",
  "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
},
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2019-06-17T10:00:00-05:00",
  "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
},
 "recurrence": [
 "EXDATE:20190617T140000Z",
 "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3;INTERVAL=1"
 ],
 "attendees": [
 ],
 "visibility": "default"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to get `EXDATE` working too. For me, using local time without `TZID` or `Z` worked, i. e.

```
EXDATE:20190617T090000
```

for your case.

P.S. This API piece seems really buggy, thus I'll mention that in my case calendar has the same timezone as the event. I do hope, that it does not matter.